# Differential forms of a Lie group giving cohomology of the Lie group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, cohomology

Consider a manifold $M$. Then, we have the notion of differential forms on $M$ and complex associated to that, denoted by $$\cdots\rightarrow \Omega^{k-1}(M)\rightarrow \Omega^k(M)\rightarrow \Omega^{k+1}(M)\rightarrow \cdots$$
giving de Rham cohomology groups $H^k_{\mathrm{dR}}(M)$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now consider a Lie group $G$. There is a notion of **cohomology of this Lie group**. Ignoring the group structure, we can talk about de Rham cohomology of the underlying manifold.

Question : Is there a notion of **restricted complex of differential forms**, that is a sub complex $\{\widetilde{\Omega^k(G)}\}$, of the complex of differential forms $\{\Omega^k(G)\}$ of $G$, whose cohomology groups gives cohomology of the Lie group?

All that (of great importance) extra structure coming in Lie group $G$ is the multiplication (and inverse) map $G\times G\rightarrow G$. So,  I am expecting this restricted differential forms to **show the action** of $G$ on itself.

By cohomology of the Lie group, I mean the cohomology of the underlying manifold. I do not think there is any notion of cohomology of Lie group. Even Google search does not give anything.

Comment: When $G$ is compact a suitable subcomplex consists of those $G$-invariant forms. When $G$ is arbitrary (connected), maybe the subcomplex of $K$-invariant forms, for $K$ maximal compact subgroup of $G$, works, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @YCor if it is already written somewhere, can you please suggest reference.. I will read :)

Comment: Wait, I am confused. When you say "cohomology of this Lie group", do you intend to mean the cohomology of the classifying space BG? You can't possibly extract this from a subcomplex of the de Rham complex because $H^*(BG)$ is nonzero in arbitrarily large degrees (and in particular past $\dim G$). If what you mean is that you want a nice complex computing cohomology of the underlying manifold then Gael's complex does what you want.

Comment: Could you clarify what notion of Lie group cohomology you're talking about?

Comment: @FernandoMuro I mean the cohomology of underlying manifold.. I am looking for some easy way to compute the cohomology.. sorry for the confusion... is it ok now?

Comment: @MikeMiller I did not think of the possible confusion... If I say cohomology of the Lie group $G$ it is not clear if I am saying about cohomology of the underlying manifold or the cohomology of topological space $BG$.. Here I mean not $BG$. Are there other possible interpretation of “cohomology of Lie group G”

Comment: @praphullakoushik if you mean the manifold cohomology you have the trivial answer: take the whole  complex. I guess this is not what you want. As pointed above, under some hypotheses (simply connected, etc.) the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex of its Lie algebra also computes the same cohomology and it has finite dimension.

Comment: I see one downvote.. if there is anything I can improve in the question, do let me know.. I may be wrong..

Comment: @FernandoMuro I mean manifold cohomology only... I do not know why it seems like this is not what I want.. I am looking for **some easy way** to compute using the Lie group structure.. I was thinking if I can take some subcomplex and still get cohomology of manifold... I will read about Chevalley-Eilenberg complex. Thanks,. It looks like you see something is not ok in my question.. Please let me know what it is.. I can explain or correct myself..

Comment: See the motivation section in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology

Comment: @FernandoMuro thank you. I will see that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every Lie group $G$, you have in your $\Omega_G$ the subcomplex of the left-invariant differential forms. Moreover, $G$ acts on the right on this subcomplex. It has the virtue of being finite-dimensional and isomorphic to a complex defined purely in terms of the Lie algebra, thus the computation of its cohomology is reduced to linear algebra.

On the other hand, considering a maximal compact subgroup $K\subseteq G$, since $G/K$ is contractible, by Poincare's lemma, $\Omega_G$ and $\Omega_K$ have the same cohomology.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer... can you give reference where this is mentioned.. May be a reference which says why this cohomology of subcomplex of differential forms is same as cohomology of the Lie group.

Comment: @Praphulla Bredon's book "Geometry and topology" has a good account.

Comment: And the cohomology of $K$ is the cohomology of $K$-invariant forms, by an averaging argument of Cartan, so you can always reduce the computation of the cohomology of $G$ to the Lie algebra cohomology of $\mathfrak{K}$.

Comment: @MikeMiller yes, I see that now..Thanks,.  it is in section 12 of chapter 5 named Differential forms on compact Lie groups... I did not saw this before..

Comment: @BenMcKay Thanks for the comment..  I do not know much about cohomology of Lie algebras.. If you can suggest some reference that talks about reducing cohomology of $G$ to that of cohomology of Lie algebra of $K$, I will read that..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You could do much worse than reading the original paper of Chevalley and Eilenberg, which is beautifully written: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-063-01/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8.pdf

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill I think the same :) I took print out just now.. I will read that :)